# How to create a tab content dynamically in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, tabs

I have created a tab at `cms/block` at admin panel along with the javascript like this:

```
    <div class="details-tab">
    <ul class="tab-links">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">Care</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab active">
            <p> {{block type="core/template" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml"}}<p>  
        </div>

        <div id="tab2" class="tab">
            <p>Tab #2 content goes here!</p>
            <p> online store.</p>
        </div>

    </div>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.details-tab .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');

        // Show/Hide Tabs
        jQuery('.details-tab ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

        // Change/remove current tab to active
        jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

And called this block in a .phtml file and it is displaying the attribute value finely. But a drawback here is that the tab1 or tab2 is left empty when there is no Value for certain products to display inside the content section of tab1 or tab2. So when There is no value to display the respective tab should be hidden.
How to do that. Please Help me.

Comment: I wanted to ask you before, (on the question you gave me no credit for my answer :)), Why do you use a cms/block and not a .phtml file? It would be easier and you could have "php if"  for what you are doing

Comment: how to do that in a .phtml file? please help me to da that. Any help will be appreciated.